# Is there an official Ubuntu Phone manufacturer?

Tags: smartphone

Is there any phone running Ubuntu? If so please tell me where I can get one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no phone that is officially running ubuntu. U have to manually install the developer preview or maybe (on a tablet) Ubuntu 13.04 Beta